# Docker local file download

Tags: docker, curl

I'm trying to dockerize my SDK as

```
docker run --rm -it -v /home/ubuntu/work/yoctosdk/:/workdir crops/extsdk-container --url file:///home/ubuntu/work/yocto/poky/build/tmp/deploy/sdk/poky-glibc-x86_64-core-image-minimal-i586-toolchain-2.4.1.sh
```

and unfortunately I am getting

```
Attempting to download file:///home/ubuntu/work/yocto/poky/build/tmp/deploy/sdk/poky-glibc-x86_64-core-image-minimal-i586-toolchain-2.4.1.sh
curl: (37) Couldn't open file /home/ubuntu/work/yocto/poky/build/tmp/deploy/sdk/poky-glibc-x86_64-core-image-minimal-i586-toolchain-2.4.1.sh
Unable to download "file:///home/ubuntu/work/yocto/poky/build/tmp/deploy/sdk/poky-glibc-x86_64-core-image-minimal-i586-toolchain-2.4.1.sh".
```

I am trying to work around this to download and run local file within docker. What would be correct download of the local file? I am following [this](https://github.com/crops/extsdk-container).

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible by default to access files from the host machine. You need to mount folders that you want to access to the Docker container.

To make the file `/home/ubuntu/work/yocto/poky/build/tmp/deploy/sdk/poky-glibc-x86_64-core-image-minimal-i586-toolchain-2.4.1.sh` accessible, mount its parent directory using:

```
-v /home/ubuntu/work/yocto/poky/build/tmp/deploy/sdk:/home/ubuntu/work/yocto/sdk-installer
```

And then provide as url the path **inside** the docker container:

```
--url file:///home/ubuntu/work/yocto/sdk-installer/poky-glibc-x86_64-core-image-minimal-i586-toolchain-2.4.1.sh
```

Full command:

```
docker run --rm -it -v /home/ubuntu/work/yoctosdk/:/workdir crops/extsdk-container -v /home/ubuntu/work/yocto/poky/build/tmp/deploy/sdk:/home/ubuntu/work/yocto/sdk-installer --url file:///home/ubuntu/work/yocto/sdk-installer/poky-glibc-x86_64-core-image-minimal-i586-toolchain-2.4.1.sh
```

Comment: seems there some script problem from https://github.com/crops/extsdk-container/ ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ docker run --rm -it -v /home/ubuntu/work/yoctosdk/:/workdir crops/extsdk-container -v /home/ubuntu/work/yocto/poky/build/tmp/deploy/sdk:/home/ubuntu/work/yocto/sdk-installer --url file:///home/ubuntu/work/yocto/sdk-installer/poky-glibc-x86_64-core-image-minimal-i586-toolchain-2.4.1.sh
usage: esdk-entry.py [-h] [--url URL] [--workdir WORKDIR]
esdk-entry.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -v /home/ubuntu/work/yocto/poky/build/tmp/deploy/sdk:/home/ubuntu/work/yocto/sdk-installer

Comment: I did it like this docker run --rm -it -v /home/ubuntu/work/yocto/poky/build/tmp/deploy/sdk/:/workdir crops/extsdk-container --url file:///workdir/poky-glibc-x86_64-core-image-minimal-i586-toolchain-2.4.1.sh - Now seems working:)